# iptables set-mark doesn't work

Tags: networking, iptables, router, port-forwarding, ntp

My machine has two network interfaces, one is wired (eth0) and the other one is wireless (wlan0). The wired one cannot connect to any external NTP server because there is a firewall outside. The wireless one has no such constraint.

Therefore, I want to route all NTP traffic to wlan0. As I know, the NTP traffic go through the UDP 123 port. What I have done is described below.

```
$ sudo echo "201 ntp.out" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
$ sudo ip route add default via 100.75.0.1 dev wlan0 table ntp.out

$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_fwmark_accept=1
$ sudo iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -p udp --dport 123 -j MARK --set-mark 0xfefa
$ sudo iptables -t mangle -I OUTPUT -p udp --sport 123 -j MARK --set-mark 0xfefa
$ sudo ip rule add fwmark 0xfefa lookup ntp.out
```

However, it doesn't work. I used Wireshark to track the UDP:123 packets, and found that there is no mark ''fefa'' in the packets.

BTW, I set net.ipv4.tcp_fwmark_accept rather than net.ipv4.udp_fwmark_accept, because there is no net.ipv4.udp_fwmark_accept defined. I also tried to mark TCP packets, but still could not find the mark in those packets.

Could anybody help me solve the problem? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Remove `sudo iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -p udp --dport 123 -j MARK --set-mark 0xfefa`, the rest look good.

Comment: I removed it, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think I find error. In not source port `123` then destination

Change

```
 sudo iptables -t mangle -I OUTPUT -p udp --sport 123 -j MARK --set-mark 0xfefa
```

to

```
 sudo iptables -t mangle -I OUTPUT -p udp --dport 123 -j MARK --set-mark 0xfefa
```

Also copy all entries except default gateway entry from main table

```
 sudo ip route show table main | grep -Ev ^default | while read ROUTE ; do ip route add table ntp.out $ROUTE; done
```